# How to give Transmission permissions to write on external HD on Raspbian Raspberry Pi media server?

Tags: permissions, raspbian, external-hdd, transmission

I've installed Transmission on my Raspberry Pi with Raspbian on.
Want to download torrents (legally of course) to an external hard drive.
Permission is denied. root is owner and group for the drive

I've tried to change permissions on the drive following a lot of different instructions here and other forums but can't make it. Found some information on that it's impossible to change permissions on a disk with exFAT.

What workaround could I do?

My main user is "pi" and I think that's the one Transmission uses.

[image: screenshot of disk in disks]

**EDIT: Add content to fstab**

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0 0
PARTUUID=50913804-01  /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults    0 2
PARTUUID=50913804-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0 1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
# use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
UUID=67E3-17ED /mnt/67E3-17ED auto defaults,nofail 0 0
UUID=652F-FA93 /mnt/652F-FA93 auto defaults,nofail 0 0
```

[image: /etc/fstab print screen]

**EDIT 2: lsblk --fs**

[image: lsblk --fs print screen]

```
$ lsblk --fs
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS  
sda                                                                         
├─sda1       vfat   FAT32 EFI   67E3-17ED            196,9M     0% /mnt/67E3-17ED
└─sda2      exfat  1.0   8TB   652F-FA93              5,8T    20% /mnt/652F-FA93
mmcblk0              
├─mmcblk0p1  vfat   FAT32 bootfs D3E6-3F09                             436,8M    14% /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2  ext4   1.0   rootfs cb6f0e18-5add-4177-ab98-e9f0235e06b3   42,7G    58% /
```

**EDIT 3: Changed fstab**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk --fs 
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                         
|-sda1
|    vfat   FAT32 EFI   67E3-17ED                             196,9M     0% /mnt/67E3-17ED
`-sda2
     exfat  1.0   8TB   652F-FA93                               5,8T    20% /mnt/652F-FA93
mmcblk0
                                                                            
|-mmcblk0p1
|    vfat   FAT32 bootfs
|                       D3E6-3F09                             436,8M    14% /boot/firmware
`-mmcblk0p2
     ext4   1.0   rootfs
                        cb6f0e18-5add-4177-ab98-e9f0235e06b3   48,4G    54% /
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -la /mnt
totalt 265
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 21 okt 16.28 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root   4096 10 okt 06.06 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 262144  7 nov 10.27 652F-FA93
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    512  1 jan  1970 67E3-17ED
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How have you **mounted** the drive?  Have you created an entry in `/etc/fstab` for mounting... if so, please edit your Q to add that info.

Comment: Thanks @Seamus!
I've added the content of the fstab.

Comment: Umm, that doesn't *look like* the contents of a proper `/etc/fstab` file. Can you C&P the entire `/etc/fstab` file into your question? Also: With this drive **plugged in** (and powered on) to your RPi, run the following command from a terminal window, and post those results here also: `lsblk --fs`.

Comment: ownership and permission of files and directories in an exFAT when mounted in Linux depends on the mount options: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/exfat-fuse/mount.exfat.8.en.html (It has been a while that the kernel has driver for exfat though. I don't know if it has exactly the same mount options as the fuse driver and which driver you are using.)

Comment: Thanks again @Seamus!
That really is the content of the /ect/fstab as you can see from the screen shot.
I've run lsblk --fs and posted the result as well.

Comment: OK, a couple of things: 1} because these comments are under your post (question), then you will need to add my handle to messages you want me to know about. Do this by simply adding `@seamus` to the comment. 2} you shouldn't use screenshots of terminal windows. Instead, C&P the actual text inside of a "code block". I've edited your question to do this.

Comment: From the output of `lsblk --fs`, it seems you've mounted both partitions of device `sda` - `sda1` & `sda2`.  However, because you're reporting a permissions issue, I'd like for you to make a change in your `fstab` file. Replace the `defaults,nofail` field with this: `rw,user,nofail`. After making this change, reboot your system, and run `lsblk --fs` again. Assuming you get the same output as before, then run `ls -la /mnt`. Report your results via an edit to your question.

Comment: @Seamus `user` has nothing to do with the permission of the content in under the mount point. It's an option to allow non-root users to get the entry mounted with `mount`.

Comment: @seamus  I've down what you suggested and posted the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. You should confirm that you have the packages installed that are needed to handle [EXFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) file systems:**

```
$ sudo apt update 
...
$ sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

If they're already installed, `apt install` will inform you of this, and do nothing further.

**2. Here's the change that should *probably* be made to your `/etc/fstab` file:**

###### FROM:

```
UUID=67E3-17ED /mnt/67E3-17ED auto defaults,nofail 0 0
UUID=652F-FA93 /mnt/652F-FA93 auto defaults,nofail 0 0
```

###### TO:

```
UUID=67E3-17ED /mnt/67E3-17ED auto defaults,nofail 0 0
UUID=652F-FA93 /mnt/652F-FA93 auto uid=pi,gid=pi,defaults,nofail 0 0
```

I say ***probably*** because I don't think you intended to download any torrents to your EFI (FAT) partition, so there's no point in changing anything. In fact, you may not actually need to include the FAT partition in your `/etc/fstab` file at all.  But, if I'm wrong, you can give the FAT partition the same treatment you gave the EXFAT partition.

If repairing the permissions is all you're interested in, you need not read the remainder of this answer. I include the remainder only to provide some background that may be helpful in the future (if your future includes such things as editing `/etc/fstab` files :)

---

The cause of this *permissions confusion* when using EXFAT is *basic*: The EXFAT filesystem has no owner/permission metadata. The owner/permission data is set when the filesystem is mounted, and it cannot be changed (unless the filesystem is remounted). This is why you see questions from time-to-time asking why `chown` and `chmod` operations fail on an EXFAT partition.

We've seen that *ownership* of an EXFAT partition is set at mount time using the `uid=` and `gid=` parameters. Permissions may also be changed; the `umask`, `dmask` and `fmask` parameters are [used for this purpose](https://www.howtogeek.com/812961/umask-linux/).

All (or most) of this is covered in the system manual: `man mount.exfat-fuse`. The challenge here is knowing the name of the manual!  :)  Which brings up a few final points with respect to formulating an entry in `/etc/fstab`:

1. I feel that use of the `auto` parameter in the third field (fs_vfstype) of `/etc/fstab` is a mistake... if you're using/editing `/etc/fstab` you should at least know what file system type you're going to mount!
2. Likewise, I feel the same re use of the `defaults` parameter in the fourth field (fs_mntops).
3. I dislike the use of UUIDs for identifying volumes to be mounted; a UUID is effectively a *random number*, and why use a random number to identify a volume to be mounted in `/etc/fstab`? ... will you remember it next week? I much prefer **LABELs** for identifying mounts. In the case of an EXFAT partition, the command for creating a label is:

```
sudo exfatlabel /dev/sda2 "TORRENT_STORE"
```

Consequently, my final suggested change to your `/etc/fstab` entry is this:

```
LABEL=TORRENT_STORE /mnt/652F-FA93 exfat uid=pi,gid=pi,rw,user,nofail 0 0
```

Comment: Not sure about Raspbian, but if exfatprogs is there, it's probably better to avoid exfat-utils and exfat-fuse in order to stick with the kernel driver. (On the other hand, depending on whether the distro has decided to keep the mount.exfat-fuse to mount.exfat symlink or not, one may need to specify exfat-fuse as the type explicitly if he/she prefers the fuse driver for whatever reason.)

Comment: Btw, apparently the fuse driver has a different default for umask (which is 0). That's probably why you have never bumped into permission problem (hence mentioning nothing about it in your guides on github).

Comment: @seamus, thank you so much for you help!
Your answer provided the solution but with one change... I did not have exfat-utils installed, nor could I install it. A bit of googling and as I understand it it's replaced by exfatprogs (Source: https://www.phoronix.com/news/Exfatprogs-Released).
Anyway when I had installed exfatprogs and edited fstab as per your suggestion using LABEL it all worked out perfectly!
Once again... THANK YOU!

Comment: @FredrikGadd Glad to hear it helped. WRT the `exfatprogs` package, I *think* what happened on my system was that when I ran the command `sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`, `apt` simply substituted `exfatprogs` for one or both of them. Kinda' surprised to see it didn't happen that way for you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently both the kernel and fuse exfat drivers use `uid`/`gid` for setting the transient ownership and `umask`/`fmask`/`dmask` for setting the transient permission of the content of the mount (including the "root" of the mount).

So you have two options. If you do not need the mount to be write accessible by users other than `pi`. You can use `uid=pi`. (You can also add `gid=pi` as well to make it like the usual case of you `HOME`. And obviously, this allows you to add `pi` as a supplementary group to other users that need to have write access to the mount.)

Certainly ownership alone does not necessarily imply the permission you need, but apparently the default `fmask` and `dmask` gives the owner `rwx` on the files and directories. (But not the owner group, which is given `r-x` by default; so `gid=pi` alone is "useless" regarding the goal mentioned above.)

If you wish to change the transient permission instead of ownership, you can have something like `fmask=0111,dmask=0000`, which gives all users `rw-` on the files and `rwx` on the directories. (You can even just set `umask=0`, which would set both `fmask` and `dmask` to `0`, i.e., `0000`, unless you use any of options explicitly as well.)